# JSON.stringify Map with nested Set

Tags: javascript, json

Consider the following graph:

```js
class Node {
  constructor(value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.adjacents = new Set();
  }

  addAdjacent(node) {
    this.adjacents.add(node);
  }
}

class Graph {
  constructor(directed = false) {
    this.nodes = new Map();
    this.directed = directed;
  }

  addVertex(value) {
    const node = this.nodes.has(value);
    if (node) {
      return this.nodes.get(value);
    }

    const vertex = new Node(value);
    this.nodes.set(value, vertex);
    return vertex;
  }

  addEdge(src, dest) {
    let srcNode = this.nodes.get(src);
    if (!srcNode) {
      srcNode = this.addVertex(src);
    }

    let destNode = this.nodes.get(dest);
    if (!destNode) {
      destNode = this.addVertex(dest);
    }

    srcNode.addAdjacent(destNode);
    if (this.directed === false) {
      destNode.addAdjacent(srcNode);
    }
  }
}

const g1 = new Graph();
g1.addVertex("a");
g1.addVertex("b");
g1.addEdge("a", "c");
```

When I `console.log` the graph object `g1`. I get the following output:

```bash
Graph {
  nodes: Map(3) {
    'a' => Node { value: 'a', adjacents: [Set] },
    'b' => Node { value: 'b', adjacents: Set(0) {} },
    'c' => Node { value: 'c', adjacents: [Set] }
  },
  directed: false
}
```

As output shows, I get no info regarding the edges of the vertices.

I tried passing `replacer` to `JSON.stringify` as follows, but it results in StackOverFlow error.

```js
console.log(
  JSON.stringify(
    Object.fromEntries(g1.nodes),
    (_key, value) =>
      value.adjacents instanceof Set ? [...value.adjacents] : value,
    2
  )
);
```

Error:

```bash
  JSON.stringify(
       ^

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
```

How can I print the graph in a more friendly format?

Comment: @Philisonstrike then how can I print it a more friendly format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's two issues here...

1. Both `Map` and `Set` do not serialise directly to JSON
2. Your data structure is cyclic and therefore cannot be serialised; node *a* is adjacent to node *c* and node *c* is adjacent to node *a*. Attempting to serialise this to a flat structure would require infinite storage.

I would recommend adding a [toJSON()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#description) method to your classes to aid in the serialisation. There, unserialisable data structures can be converted to simple ones and cyclic references can be broken.

For example

```js
class Node {
  constructor(value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.adjacents = new Set();
  }

  addAdjacent(node) {
    this.adjacents.add(node);
  }

  toJSON() {
    return {
      ...this,
      // plain array with scalar values
      adjacents: [...this.adjacents].map(({ value }) => value),
    };
  }
}

class Graph {
  constructor(directed = false) {
    this.nodes = new Map();
    this.directed = directed;
  }

  addVertex(value) {
    const node = this.nodes.has(value);
    if (node) {
      return this.nodes.get(value);
    }

    const vertex = new Node(value);
    this.nodes.set(value, vertex);
    return vertex;
  }

  addEdge(src, dest) {
    let srcNode = this.nodes.get(src);
    if (!srcNode) {
      srcNode = this.addVertex(src);
    }

    let destNode = this.nodes.get(dest);
    if (!destNode) {
      destNode = this.addVertex(dest);
    }

    srcNode.addAdjacent(destNode);
    if (this.directed === false) {
      destNode.addAdjacent(srcNode);
    }
  }

  toJSON() {
    return {
      ...this,
      // reduce the Map entries to a simple object
      nodes: Object.fromEntries(this.nodes),
    };
  }
}

const g1 = new Graph();
g1.addVertex("a");
g1.addVertex("b");
g1.addEdge("a", "c");

console.log(JSON.stringify(g1, null, 2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```